# 撮影後カメラ画面が切り替わるタイミングで開始するアクションを実装したい

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera

「ボタンを押すとカメラが起動し、撮影してカメラ画面がメインビューに切り替わったタイミングでビューに追加している画像が消える」
という仕様にしたいのですが、うまくいきません。
どのようにすればうまくいくでしょうか？

yagi.hidden = true; をカメラ画面を閉じた後に実行させたいので、後ろにそのままいれています。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
 UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   let myImage = UIImage(named: "ume")
            ume.image = myImage
  }

@IBOutlet weak var yagi: UIImageView!

@IBAction func launchCamera(sender: UIButton) {

let camera = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(camera){
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = camera
picker.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, 
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

yagi.hidden = true;

   }
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
のcompletionがviewがdismissされた後に実行されるので、completionに

```
{ [unowned self] in self.yagi.hidden = true }
```

を渡して実行すると良いと思います。